# Setting Sublime Text 3 to run specific Java version

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I have Java 11 and 7 installed since I am maintaining a website that uses Java 7. Some IDE now only support Java 11 onward, so I was figuring out how to set Sublime Text 3 to specifically run Java 7, without changing the default Java 11 on my system. I manage to figure it out by putting multiple pieces together, so I am documenting the answer here for other's reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On Sublime Text 3, go to "Tools" > "Build System" > "New Build System..."
2. Paste the following piece of code. Edit the `path` setting accordingly. I'm using Zulu JDK.

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name", "&&", "java", "$file_base_name"],
    "selector": "source.java",
    "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\JDK-Zulu\\zulu-7\\bin",
    "shell": true
}
```

3. Save the setting with extension `.sublime-build`. I named mine `Java7 Run.sublime-build`.
4. After saving, it should appear in your Build System list. Select that and now when you Build, it will use Java 7 (or whatever Java version you set it to be).

To validate, you can use `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`

Comment: I just tried to modify your validation to validate the javac compiler via sublime text, but I received null because, in retrospect, the _.class file is being run with java, not javac :) (novice here). Is there any direct way to validate the compiler Sublime Text is accessing? For reference, my javaC.sublime-build file shows ```"shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\""``` which I interpret to indicate that sublime text is running whatever javac is default to my shell. And in my shell, ```javac -version``` returns my desired version, so unless I've missed something, I should be well set, yes?

Answer (score 0):

On the  Mac Os, thats my path: `"path": "/Users/<your-home-dir>/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open/bin"`.
I use sdkman for various jdk flavors.

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && java $file_base_name && rm *.class"],
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell": true,
    "variants": [

      {
        "name": "JavaDoc",
        "cmd": ["mkdir documentation && javadoc -d documentation *.java"]
       },

       {
        "name": "JAR",
        "cmd": ["javac '$realpath$file' && echo \"Main-Class: $file_base_name\" > Manifest.txt && jar cfm $file_base_name.jar Manifest.txt *.class && rm *.class && java -jar $file_base_name.jar"]
        },


       {
        "name": "List Files",
        "cmd": ["ls"],
        },

       {
        "name": "Word Count",
        "cmd": ["wc", "$file"]
       }
    ],
    
    "path": "/Users/<your-home-dir>/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open/bin"
}
```